# AppleScript to Option-click on the Dropbox Menu Bar Icon

Tags: keyboard, applescript, menu-bar, dropbox

I have an AppleScript that does a simple "mouse" click on the Dropbox menu bar icon (**Menu Extra** or **Menulet**). It works well.

```
tell application "System Events"
tell UI element "Dropbox"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        perform action "AXPress"
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

I want to edit this code so the action that will be performed is a **click** while the **Option** (<kbd>alt / ⌥</kbd>) is pressed down.

I've done an extensive search for a solution but didn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most (I think all) of the menu options in the Dropbox menu bar popup menu are also available through the standard click popup window and then a second click on the preferences icon.  Perhaps accessing your desired menu items that way is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using terms from the (FREE) [AppleScript Toolbox](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/) scripting addition, this code will handle your question.

---

The code in this updated answer will automatically get the coordinates of the DROPBOX icon in the status bar...  Whether it's location stays the same or changes

---

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its UI element "Dropbox"
        tell its menu bar 2
            set originalCoordinates to position
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

set itemOne to (item 1 of originalCoordinates) + 10
set itemTwo to (item 2 of originalCoordinates) + 10

set dropboxMouseLocation to {itemOne, itemTwo}
AST set mouse point location dropboxMouseLocation
AST click at dropboxMouseLocation holding modifier key ast option key
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

This is following version of the code will return the mouse to where its original location was before clicking on the Dropbox status menu icon

---

```
set originalMouseLocation to AST mouse point location

tell application "System Events" to tell its UI element "Dropbox"
    tell its menu bar 2
        set originalCoordinates to position
    end tell
end tell

set itemOne to (item 1 of originalCoordinates) + 10
set itemTwo to (item 2 of originalCoordinates) + 10

set dropboxMouseLocation to {itemOne, itemTwo}
AST set mouse point location dropboxMouseLocation
AST click at dropboxMouseLocation holding modifier key ast option key

AST set mouse point location originalMouseLocation
```

Comment: Love your Gifs! What program do you use to create it?

Comment: http://gifbrewery.com/  is generally what I use for animated GIFs

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is a definitely a valid option, but, can it be done using UI scripting rather than coordinates? It’s more reliable, and my status bar tends to change quite often.

Comment: @voronoi I have tried every other possible approach I could think of...  The only solution I can get to work is the original solution I posted.

Comment: @wch1zpink, thank you very much. Is there at least a way to "get" the coordinates of the UI element, setting it as a variable, and then invoking the commands on it? This could be a nice, reliable workaround that will be valid regardless of the menu bar's state.

Comment: @voronoi Great question...  Updated the code.  It's no longer necessary to manually set coordinates.  Now wherever the dropbox icon sits, the code will automatically work

Comment: Beautiful! It worked superbly! Thanks @wch1zpink!
The one thing that would make this script truly perfect is to add the necessary code to get the original pointer coordinates (before the script was initiated), and after the click has been done, revert the pointer back to its initial position.
1. How do I do that?
2. What do the "10" numbers stand for?
Thanks!

Comment: The code "set originalCoordinates to position" returns the location where the upper left corner of the placement of the icon sits.  So if "set originalCoordinates to position" returns {1083, 0}, adding +10 to each one of those values will give us these new coordinates... {1093, 10} <--- which is actually where we want the mouse to click.  Code updated as per your request.  Don't forget to mark my post as the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: You couldn't be more helpful! Thanks! One further question, for learning's sake: how does the logic behind this whole concept of "coordinates" in macOS/AppleScript work? Are they absolute? Or relative? (if relative, then to what?) Will specifying the same coordinates always result in the same position across different machines and screen sizes and resolutions?

Comment: Sadly, AppleScript Toolbox died in Mojave, a few months after this answer was posted. You can read the obituary here: <https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/2018/10/02/the-end-of-applescript-toolbox/>